# How to count specific character live onkeyup with jquery in each column?

Tags: jquery

I got the script to count specific character from lines of strings. Which is 70 lines counted. But whenever I put in each textarea. I counts the same value. Please take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/hp3t7kju/3/

```
$('.counter').on('keyup',function(){
var str=$('textarea').val();
var count = (str.match(/=/g) || []).length;
$(this).find('span').html(count);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there . You need to find `textarea` inside `counter` class using `this` to get different count. Otherwise it's take first `textarea` and gives same result.

```js
$('.counter').on('keyup',function(){
    var str=$(this).find('textarea').val();
    var count = (str.match(/=/g) || []).length;
    $(this).find('span').html(count);
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input1</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input2a" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input2</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input3a" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input3</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input2b" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply and the easiest solution is to use [.children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function to check which `textarea` is being `keyup`

`$(this)` refer to the element which we are keyup function on currently when typing.

**Demo**

```js
$('.counter').on('keyup', function() {
  var str = $(this).children('textarea').val()
  var count = (str.match(/=/g) || []).length;
  $(this).find('span').html(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input1</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input2a" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input2</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input3a" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 counter">
      <strong>Input3</strong> <span class="text-danger"></span><br />
      <textarea name="input2b" rows="10" class="form-control" cols="5"></textarea><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```